# pylint3 Variable name "fl" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)

Tags: pylint, snakecasing

According to this [pylint-wiki](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103), it seems that 2 letter variable names are ok:

> Variable  variable-rgx    [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$

But for some reason I get the following error:

```
Variable name "fl" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regular expression says:

- A letter or underscore
- Followed by at least 2 letters, underscores or digits

In total this sums up to at least 3 characters per variable name.

Comment: oh my ! completely missed that ... after so many years of teaching reg-exps ... I hope none of my students land here :))